# Composite simpson rule infinity output

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, calculus

Algorthim:[image]

i have the following code which calculates improper integrals using composite Simpson rule, i am trying to evalute the integral `exp(-x)/sqrt(1-x)` where `a= 0` and `b = 1` and while `n=6` or the steps =6. However, I keep getting the output to be infinity when it should be `= 4.288`

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

    double f(double x)
    {


        return exp(-x)/sqrt(1-x);
    }

    double simpson(double a, double b, double n)
    {

    double x0=f(a)+f(b);

    double x1=0,x2=0;
    double x=0;
    double h=(b-a)/(n);
    for(int i = 1 ; i <n;i++){

            x=a+(h*i);
            if(i%2==0)
            {
                x2=x2+f(x);
            }
            else
            {
                x1=x1+f(x);
            }


        }
            return (h*(x0+2*x2+4*x1))/3;
;
    }

     int main(){
          cout<<endl;
               cout<<"The improper integral is: "<<simpson(0.00000009,1,6)<<" "<<endl;
               cout<<endl;
        }
```

Comment: are you evaluating at x=1? From the definition of `h` and `n` it seems you are.

Comment: it should evaluate the integral from lowerbound = 0 till the upper bound = 1, while n=6

Comment: at x=1, your function goes to infinity. You need to guard that.

Comment: @macroland but isnt the purpose of the algorthim to compute that indefinite integral? or what other possible solution?

Comment: the algorithm is just to compute the integral. Just give a tolerance say 1E-5 and subtract from the bound. By the way, n=6 seems too little.

Comment: Btw, bear in mind that, the accuracy of the integration for this particular function is very sensitive to the tolerance level you will choose for `b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that the function `f(double x)` you are evaluating is not defined at x = 1, since it is equal to `exp(-1)/sqrt(1 - 1)` which is dividing by zero, yet you are calling `f(b)` in the first line of `simpson` when b is 1. You are therefore returning infinity. You might want to set b to 0.9999 instead. If you do this with a much larger value of n for closer approximation to the actual curve (say n = 400), you get very close to the actual answer of 1.076 as found by @macroland on Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: i get: The improper integral is: 2.92876

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+exp%28-x%29%2Fsqrt%281-x%29+from+0+to+1

Comment: thanks, so it's almost impossible to gets it accurate value at n=6?

Comment: It depends on the function @sanjep, but Simpson's method is likely to be inaccurate in a small range where f(x) tends to infinity. If you test it against the range a = 0, b = 0.5 it should be close to perfect.